# Input field doesn't get checked attribute

Tags: php, html, input, checked

I have a form with an input field. If they click on a specific `daypart` I want the input field to be `checked`. I try to do that with the following code, but the field doesn't get the attribute `checked` when I check it.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dayparts[]" value="<?php echo $daypart['id']?>" <?php if (!empty($_GET['dayparts'] == '1')){ echo 'checked';}?> >
```

This is the url when I check something.

```
index.php?page=activities&dayparts%5B%5D=1
```

Comment: When I have had similar issue it was often that checked is not a straight bool. I have found that it is often an array with 0 or 1. so if I miss the array traversal I won't ever get a 0 or 1 for the checked value

Comment: @ChrisRichardson Dayparts is an array, so it shouldn't be dayparts == 1 ?

Comment: $dayparts['id'] would probably === 1 but $dayparts might not

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dayparts[]" value="<?php echo $daypart['id']?>" <?php if (!empty($_GET['dayparts'] == '1')){ echo 'checked';}?> >
```

I think above code have a problem .The problem is

```
<?php if (!empty($_GET['dayparts'] == '1')){ echo 'checked';}?>
```

This part .Please check you `$GET['dayparts']` .But In url you pass `dayparts%5B%5D`.
This is the problem .For this reason `<?php if (!empty($_GET['dayparts'] == '1')){ echo 'checked';}?>` is not check .And you get this error.
Url will be

```
index.php?page=activities&dayparts=1
```